# Find which files are touched by a program - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, temporary-files

I have a third-part library that make a temp file somewhere. I need to find where because I have to give to that folder the correct security properties (now I can run this library only as administrator due to this trouble).
How can I monitor my Filesystem to find which file are touched or created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) by SysInternal can do this!

Answer (score 0):

You can get **File-Handles** by using Windows Built-in `Resource Monitor` just open `"run.exe" > "resmon.exe"`
Now Resource monitor has opened. Go to "CPU" Tab and select a process which you want to see the handles. Now you can see Handles by opening The drawer "`Associated modules`" and "`Associated modules`".